# Connect MacBook Air to Cisco 2811 Console (RS-232 serial)

Tags: mac, macos, router

<strike>I'm trying to console connect into my business's Cisco 2811 console with my MacBook Air with a Thunderbolt to Gigabit adapter. I've googled around for a day and haven't found any information.</strike>

How can I connect to my router with my MacBook Air using the Thunderbolt adapter?

EDIT:
I've purchased the proprietary Cisco console cable which is an RJ-45 to DB9 rollover 
cable.
Then I purchased a DB9 to usb adapter to plug into the MBA but when I try to follow

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/connectedgrid/cgr1000/hardware/cgr1240/app.console.html#wp1049053

I don't get anything under *usb*.

Comment: What I've tried so far is a simple tty through all my tty connections in /dev/.

Answer (score 1):

Serial is not Ethernet, these are two different protocols, so connecting it to your thunderbolt adapter won't work. You can use a USB-serial cable for this, I've had good experiences with cables with a PL2303 chipset on OSX.

Comment: So is there any other way I can connect to the router to make config changes? SSH? Telnet? Any other means? Without having to buy special cables/adapters?

Comment: That totally depends on the current configuration of the router.

Answer (score 0):

The "console" port on a Cisco router is for a serial connection, so you would need a USB-to-serial adapter and the appropriate cable to connect that way. Cisco routers can also be set up to be configured via telnet, and I think the nicer ones do SSH (or maybe all the new ones do now, I don't know, but SSH adds a lot of code for router firmware that is supposed to be tight and devoted to the bare minimum required for routing packets). So you would be able to connect to it that way without special equipment or programs, from anywhere within its internal network and possibly its external one, depending on configuration.

Comment: I'm not getting why I need a USB-to-serial adapter. The console port on the router is a RJ-45 port. In my Cisco class I remember connecting a rollover cable to a DB-9 adapter and then serial but then newer routers came out where I thought you could just CAT-5 rollover straight to the NIC of the PC you want to edit the configurations from.

Comment: The signalling is different. Ethernet and serial are just different protocols. They use the same connectors and wires, but the way signals are encoded is totally different. As @ash indicated you can use telnet and SSH to manage routers, but for initial configuration console access is needed.

Comment: So this is what I remember using in the Cisco class to ethernet into the console port with a CAT-5 rollover cable.

http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/linux/SGI_EndUser/books/SGIconsole_HW_CG/sgi_html/figures/pinout.RJ45-to-DB9.adapter.gif

If I got one of those but instead of Serial it went to USB could I achieve the same goal?

Comment: That cable uses the db9 connector on the PC-side to connect to the serial port there. A typical USB-serial cable has db9-male on the other side so you can connect a default Cisco serial cable (the lightblue one) to it.

Comment: I've purchased the DB9 to usb adapter to connect to the cisco serial cable but I don't get the *USB* connection under any my /dev/tty. How can I install drivers for this cable?

Answer (score 0):

If SSH is enabled on the router you can plug into the network interface of a connected switch (or anywhere on the network) and open **Terminal**.

Type> **SSH** XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX being the ip of the router, ex. 10.0.1.1)

If SSH is enabled you should be prompted for a username or login depending on the device. The 2811 may just ask for a password at that point (been awhile since I have logged into one).

If it times out then SSH is not enabled on the router and this is a configuration on the router itself. Then the USB to serial to Cisco Console Cable is going to be your best route to connect. I use Tripp-Lite USB to Serial adapters and have had no problems. They are about $20.

I have used both these methods as a network admin and it works for Cisco switch configs.

Comment: My problem is I don't know the IP of the router. Is there a way I can crawl the network to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I use a mac to connect to cisco routers daily.

You are on the right track.  You have the correct equipment... Now you need to install a driver for the USB to serial adapter.

If you have OSX 10.x and you purchased a generic adapter such as the TRENDnet TU-S9 USB to serial adapter, you can simply download and the driver from [here](http://www.trendnet.com/support/supportdetail.asp?prod=265_TU-S9).  Install it, reboot, and you should see `/dev/tty.usbserial` when you run the command `ls -ltr /dev/*usb*`.

If you are using some other USB to serial adapter, post the output of the command `ioreg -p IOUSB -l` and I will try to help.